# almost integer with an exponential and involving the number pi

Tags: number-theory

we know that the number $ \exp(\pi \sqrt {163}) $ is almost an integer

my question is if there are an infinite or finite number of integers $k$ so

$ \exp(\pi \sqrt k) $ are almost integers with an error of $10^{-q} $ for some $q$ integer